# Как загрузить содержимое файла в список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ребятки, открываю текстовый файл пытаюсь его строки выгрузить в список. Но питон ругается на это:

```
f = open('marki.txt') 
spisokf = [for line in f] 
f.close() 
f2 = open('mymarki.txt') 
spisokf2 =[for line in f2] 
f2.close()
```

А именно на [for line in f]

Подскажите чайнику.

Файлы имеют следующий вид:

BMW X5
Toyota
Жигули
Запорожец

Полный код программы выглядит следующим образом:

```
f = open('marki.txt')
f2 = open('mymarki.txt')

spisokf = [for line in f]

spisokf2 =[for line in f2]

spisoknew =[]

for i in spisokf2:
    if i in spisokf:
        print(i + " уже есть в списке!")
    if i not in spisokf:
        spisoknew.append(i)

f3 = open('newmarki.txt', 'w')

for i in spisoknew:
    f3.write(i + '\n')

answer = input('Программа сработала! Нажмите любую клавишу, чтобы закрыть программу!')
```

Программа выгружает ключи с 1 файла, выгружает ключи с 2 файла. Сверяет имеются ли такие ключи в файле 1, и те которые уникальные, заносит в список и затем сохраняет в файл 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите `spisokf = f.readlines()` вместо `spisokf = [for line in f]`

Comment: Ругается: line 2, in <module>
    spisokf = f.readlines()

Comment: @kelevra Как именно ругается нужно указывать.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/ZrJjw6YigNkxrj

Comment: @kelevra, при открытии еще кодировку указать надо: `open('mymarki.txt', encoding='cp1251')`. Всегда указывайте в вопросе конкретные ошибки (причем лучше текстом, а не скриншотом).

Comment: Вы Гений! Заработало! Огромной спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает выражения перед `for`:

```
[line for line in f]
```

Но проще написать:

```
list(f)
```